# A fluid artifacts, strange long splashes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: fluid-simulation, artifacts

I've checked all the normals, meshes, tried to redraw all, scale down the fluids, tried clean blender installation, another computer with a fresh 2.76 blender. The results are similar. So I guess something wrong with the scene itself. I've spent 20 hours on this and still don't understand what's wrong. Please, any ideas?
[image: The first frame of the simulation]

The higher fluid resolution the more "splashes".
The blend file: [fluid-cans.blend](https://github.com/thima2017/tempfiles/raw/master/fluid-cans.blend)

Comment: Something hidden was on the upper fluid mesh. Limited Dissolve + Delete Loose + Remove Doubles helped. I didn't try Limited Dissolve before because I wanted to keep that native mesh. If there is an other way to find mesh issues without dissolving, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to scale up everything, in every simulation in Blender for an acceptable result. You have to rise the upper can to don't intersect each other, and it's better if you switch the slips to no slip on every obstacles.[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XGvaz4nLbSgsU5t--XnoVmGuQrf9AW2P)